# PHP returning specific data from another class

Tags: php, variables

PHP question on how to return a specific value from another class in a seperate file. So I have created a uploader class to handle and store files uploaded by users. But trying to connect the dots back to the orginal request which if for lets say a specific page - how can i pass a specific value back after I set the values in the other file... code example below.

Thanks Citti

```
//file 1 //store page request
public function store()
{
    //pass the uploaded file to be uploaded and stored
    $this->uploader->upload(RequestFile::file('assetfile'));

    $page = new Page;
        $page->user_id = $asset->user()->id;
        $page->assetfile = $file->user_id; <--- ? see below
    $page->save();
}

//file 2 //store physical file and create record in DB
class Uploader {

   public function upload($file)
   {
       $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $string = str_random(30);
       $uploadName = $string . '.' . $extension;
       $destinationPath = storage_path() . '/app/uploads/' . Request::user()->id;

       $file->move($destinationPath, $uploadName);

       $file = new File;
           $file->user_id = $asset->user()->id;
           $file->assetfile = $uploadId;
       $file->save();

       $return $file->user_id; ?!?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return values from a function, you use "return value" and you just have to store that to a variable or output it. Something like:

```
public function store() {
    $fileId = $this->uploader->upload(RequestFile::file('assetfile'));
    $page = new Page;
    $page->user_id = $asset->user()->id;
    $page->assetfile = $fileId;
    $page->save();
}

//file 2 //store physical file and create record in DB
class Uploader {
   public function upload($file) {
       $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $string = str_random(30);
       $uploadName = $string . '.' . $extension;
       $destinationPath = storage_path() . '/app/uploads/' . Request::user()->id;
       $file->move($destinationPath, $uploadName);
       $file = new File;
       $file->user_id = $asset->user()->id;
       $file->assetfile = $uploadId;
       $file->save();
       return $file->user_id;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is session variables?

Be sure to start sessions on both file 1 and file 2 via:

`session_start();`

Now, in your upload function, you can declare a session variable
`$_SESSION['specificValue'] = $valueSetInUpload;`

Now, back on your first file you can access the variable inside of your store function with
`$valueSetInUpload = $_SESSION['specificValue'];`

I believe this is what you are asking, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I try to stay away from sessions as they can become corrupt and depending on behavior they can get hairy. 
also if i have a form that has multiple file uploads you wouldn't want this behavior. as you would want to return multiple fileIds for the seperate file uploads. 
thanks tho.

Comment: @Citti Interesting, I've never heard of corrupting sessions - also, sessions allow arrays.